# Lightning:tabset does not refresh on mobile devices?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, winter18

Noticed that Lightning tabset is not refreshing on mobile devices.
This can be simulated on browser as well. When it appears on a mobile device initially it appears as,

[image]

After clicking on different tab it will be refreshed to below.

[image]

Also on Android chrome/Apple safari this is not refreshing at all. We need to scroll the device screen right to see the tabs.
I believe this worked fine before winter 18. Not sure if there is a refresh() method to refresh the view after initializing. Note this is not a dynamically added tab, it's all in the markup.

Appreciate any suggestions, help on this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the solution for same?. Also when we click on next icon it scrolls multiple tab at a time rather than one tab at a time.

Comment: Hi @PankajAndhale I just posted the fix used as a workaround, no other solutions found yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used below event as a workaround, and that fixed the issue.

Markup:

```
<aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.doneRendering}"/>
```

Controller:

```
doneRendering: function(component, event, helper){
    // Update tab layout for mobile
    var device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");

    if(device == "PHONE"){
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('slds-tabs--scoped__nav');
        for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.display = 'list-item';
            elements[i].style.textAlign  = 'center';
        }
    }
},
```